# MySql query on 3 different tables

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables.

Owners:

```
ownerID name
   1    josh
```

Pets:

```
petID name
  1    M
  2    x
  3    f
  4    h
```

PetsOwners:

```
petID  ownerID
  1       1
  3       1
  4       1
```

I have a query that returns the ownerID from a person. "SELECT ownerID FROM Owners WHERE name = 'josh';" This will return ownerID = 1. I need a query that returns all pets that josh owns. In this case will be "m", "f" and "h" according to the petsOwners table.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `ownerId` use

```
 SELECT p.name
 FROM Pets  p
 JOIN PetsOwners po
   ON p.petID = po.petID
 WHERE po.ownerID = 1
```

If you only have the owner name, need join all 3 tables

```
 SELECT p.name
 FROM Pets  p
 JOIN PetsOwners po
   ON p.petID = po.petID
 JOIN Owners o
   ON po.ownerID = o.ownerID
 WHERE o.name = 'josh'
```

Comment: This works great. How can I add to this query a ExoticPet table and a ExoticOwners?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want their names:

```
SELECT Pets.name 
FROM Pets, PetsOwners, Owners
WHERE Pets.petID = PetsOwners.petID 
AND Owners.ownerID = PetsOwners.ownerID;
```

Comment: Promote the use of  explict `JOIN` sintaxis, Aaron Bertrand wrote a nice article [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) about it.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select a.ownerID,a.`name`as OwnerName, b.petID,b.`name` as PetName from
(select ownerID `name` from Owners) as a
right join
(select a.petID,a.`name`,OwnerID from
(select petID,`name` from Pets) as a
left JOIN
(select petID,OwnerID from PetsOwners) as b
on a.petID = b.petID) as b
on a.ownerID = b.OwnerID
```

Answer (score 0):

I see your question and this is easy you see the query I wrote blow:

```sql
SELECT links.`link`,
       links.`link_id`
FROM links
WHERE links.`link_id` NOT IN
    (SELECT Y.`link_id`
     FROM users X
     INNER JOIN user_visited Y ON X.`user_id` = Y.`user_id`
     WHERE X.`user_id` = 22 );
```